# Paypal integration to android application

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I added a sample code to my application and run it. It showed me an alert as shown below.

[image: paypal alert message]

I searched for it fount this  [paypal link](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-here-compatible-devices) which says that not all android devices are supported by paypal. To check if mine is supported I should download and run paypal app on my device.

Next issue occurs when I search for paypal in play store. I don't see paypal app in play store.

Has anyone faced this problem? Any hint or suggestion?

**Note :** I want to transfer money using Paypal account, not credit card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had not set `ClientID` when starting PaymentActivity.

```
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT,
                PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX);

intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID); // Set Client Id

startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Here probably doesn't support the country you live in.

My country is unsupported aswell.

Comment: The account is created from US which paypal supports.

Answer (score 0):

(Log In - With PayPal account)
First enter here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

Then: 
  Choose "Create Application"
     In this step, you need to choose Mobile SDK insted of Web. Write a name of your app and the press the button 'create'.

Finish this, press in the name of your app and choose **REST API CREDENTIALS**

inside ther you will see something like: **"Test Credentials" and "Live Credentials"** in test credentials are client_id tag, well copy that tag, something like:

`aafsdsdssdsf3434famAp_o0Rdafadsafa334__O`

then in your app have something like and paste the cliend_id here:

```
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE to move real money.
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials from https://developer.paypal.com
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires without communicating to PayPal's servers.
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
***private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "PASTE HERE";***
// when testing in sandbox, this is likely the -facilitator email address. 
private static final String CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "matching paypal email address";
```

finish run your app again.

Remember this code are inside "MainActivity.java" inside PayPalSDK

For real live and pay: use client of **Live Credentials tag**

Comment: what is the need of secreate and api access values.am doing what you said its working for sand box money transfered from one place to another.my doubt is what about secreate and apiaccess things.